# "Socket is closed" exception when using a Socket that is passed to a Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am making a simple Web Server where I spawn a new thread each time a client connects. I then need to send a response using a BufferedOutputStream(since the HTTP protocol requires a /r/n at the end of the line).
Here is my code:

```
class HttpServer{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ServerSocket ss = null;
        int port = 40000;

        try{
            if(args.length > 0){
                port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            }

            ss = new ServerSocket(port);

            while(true){
                Socket client = ss.accept();
                User user = new User(client);
                user.start();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And my User class:

```
class User extends Thread{

        Socket client;

        public User(Socket s){
            client = s;
        }

        public void run(){
            try{
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

                println(bos, "Hello World");
                bos.close();

                client.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        private void println(BufferedOutputStream bos, String s) throws IOException { 
            String news = s + "\r\n"; 
            byte[] array = news.getBytes(); 
            for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
                bos.write(array[i]);
            }
            return;
        }
    }
```

The problem occurs when I try and create the BufferedOutputStream; it gives me a "Socket is closed" error and I have no idea why.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

This is the code that doesn't work:

```
class User extends Thread{

    Socket client;

    public User(Socket s){
        client = s;
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            System.out.println("Address: " + client.getInetAddress().toString());

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            Boolean first = true;
            while(!((line = reader.readLine()).equals(""))){
                if(first)
                    System.out.println(line.split(" ")[1]);
                first = false;
            }
            reader.close();

            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            println(bos, "Hello World");
            bos.close();



            // Close socket
            client.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void println(BufferedOutputStream bos, String s) throws IOException { 
        String news = s + "\r\n"; 
        byte[] array = news.getBytes(); 
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            bos.write(array[i]);
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: weird, i don't know what's happening

Comment: How does the client call your server? Perhaps the client closes the connection before reading any output from the server?

Comment: I have been testing it by entering localhost:40000 in a browser, and that is the result. I also tried using a local address e.g. 192.168.0.100:40000 with the same result.

Comment: The code is fine: I have tested it with both `telnet` and a browser: Both show "Hello World", and there is no error on the server side. Packet filter? Firewall? Did you turn off the web proxy in your browser so that it's really a direct connect?

Comment: @Beryllium I have done exactly the same thing, and have the same results.

Comment: Ah so it does work. I actually had some other code in there which I took out because I thought it was fine. I've appended the original code to the main post. Why does it not work when I read the HTTP request as well?

Comment: Okay I've solved it. It turns out closing the reader also closes the socket. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInputStream() So I just didn't close my reader.

Answer (score 3):

This exception means that *you* closed the Socket.

Closing the input stream or the output stream of a socket closes the other two, and closing any FilterInput/OutputStream/Reader/Writer closes the stream/reader/writer it is filtering.

Answer (score -1):

So far as I can tell, there is no problem with your code. It seems more likely that the operating system or browser is restricting access to your server in some way.

Comment: The meaning of the exception is that he is closing the socket and then continuing to use it. This is indisputably a problem in his code.

Answer (score -1):

```
Socket client = ss.accept();
User user = new User(client);
user.start();
```

The `accept` call blocks waiting for connections. Your User thread is never created. You should create  a new User class which creates a new thread for you and writes your messages to the server.

```
    public class User extends Thread{

            Socket client;
            int port;
            public User(int p) throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
                port = p;
                client = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 40000);
            }

            public void run(){
                try{
                    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

                    println(bos, "Hello World");
                    bos.close();

                    client.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            private void println(BufferedOutputStream bos, String s) throws IOException { 
                String news = s + "\r\n"; 
                byte[] array = news.getBytes(); 
                for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
                    bos.write(array[i]);
                }

                return;
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
                User user = new User(4000);
                user.start();
            }
        }
```

The server should only listen to incoming connections.(and perhaps print it)

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;


class HttpServer{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ServerSocket ss = null;
        int port = 40000;

        try{
            if(args.length > 0){
                port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            }

            ss = new ServerSocket(port);

            while(true){
                Socket client = ss.accept();
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(client.getInputStream());
                while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Run both of them as different java processes and you should see hello world at server side.
If you change your port you may have to change this on the client side too.

Comment: The User *is* the accepted connection, not a new client connection from inside the server. You haven't understood the code at all. -1